# cannot do ng-click event on ion-spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

[image: Please refer to this image]

I am using Ionic framework to make a mobile app.
I created a ion spinner on the head bar with the following code:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="primary" ng-click="say();">
<ion-spinner icon="lines" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner>
</ion-nav-buttons>

$scope.say = function(){
    console.log('abc');
    alert('hihi);
}
```

But I cannot do ng-click or any touch/click event with it. I think spinner is a cool icon and it would be nice to be able to click on it. Is there a way I can click on the spinner and call a $scope func=function(){} in the controller?

Comment: `<ion-nav-buttons side="primary" ng-click="test()">
<ion-spinner icon="lines" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner>
</ion-nav-buttons>` try with these code  add `ng-click` in `<ion-nav-buttons>` tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are not able to add the ng-click directive to the svg element for the spinner.

The solution I came up with was to wrap the spinner in a div element and bring its z-index to the front so it is displayed in front of the spinner(The spinner is still visible). You will have to change your controller code to match your app name, controller name, etc.

Live Preview: http://codepen.io/larryjoelane/pen/KVGddX

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ionNavBar">
  <!--begin app container, the ng app would normally be placed in the opening html tag-->


  <ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">

      <div ng-click="say();" id="spinner">
        <ion-spinner icon="lines" class="spinner-balanced"></ion-spinner>
      </div>


    </ion-nav-buttons>
  </ion-nav-bar>

  <br>
  <br>

</div>
<!--end app container-->
```

CSS:

```
.spinner svg {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  stroke: #999;
  fill: #999;
}

#spinner{
  z-index:1000;

}
```

Angular/JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module("app",['ionic']);

app.controller("ionNavBar",["$scope",function($scope){


  $scope.say = function(){

    alert("say function was called.")

  };


}]);//end controller
```

Comment: So I tried this:


<ion-nav-buttons side="primary" ng-click="say();">


$scope.say = function(){
        console.log('abcdef');
        alert('hihi');
    }

And it did not work

Comment: I believe I reconstructed the necessary parts of your app. Check out the live preview in my answer when you get a chance I believe it was you are trying to achieve.